# Pandas new dataframe based on combinations of all values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have collected location data from buses over some time and want to build a model predicting when a bus will arrive at a certain stop.

In its most simple form, I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'station': ['Station 1', 'Station 2', 'Station 3', 'Station 4'], 
                    'arrival_time': ['10:00', '10:02', '10:03', '10:05']})
print(df)

     station arrival_time
0  Station 1        10:00
1  Station 2        10:02
2  Station 3        10:03
3  Station 4        10:05
```

I would like to map the arrival time at each station to the arrival time at a station later in the trip. The expected output looks something like this:

```
  station_prev arrival_time_prev station_next arrival_time_next
0    Station 1             10:00    Station 2             10:02
1    Station 2             10:02    Station 3             10:03
2    Station 3             10:03    Station 4             10:05
3    Station 1             10:00    Station 3             10:03
4    Station 2             10:02    Station 4             10:05
5    Station 1             10:00    Station 4             10:05
```

I have experimented with df.shift() and the following works for singular DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def combos(df):
    
    columns_prev = np.array(df.columns) + '_prev'
    columns_next = np.array(df.columns) + '_next'
 
    df_combo = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
        df_prev = df.shift(i)
        df_prev.columns = columns_prev
        df_next = df.copy()
        df_next.columns = columns_next
        combo = pd.concat([df_prev, df_next], axis=1).dropna()
        df_combo = df_combo.append(combo, ignore_index=True)
    
    return df_combo
```

However, it is quite slow for larger DataFrames and regularly breaks when I try to wrap it into a larger function that aggregates data from many trips (I often get key errors, but do not understand why). Any ideas on how to do this more elegantly, efficiently and reliably? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide us with the key errors you often get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert "station" to an ordered categorical column:

```
df['station'] = pd.Categorical(df['station'], ordered=True).codes
```

You can now do a cross join and filter:

```
tmp = df.assign(key=1)
(tmp.merge(tmp, on='key', suffixes=('_prev', '_next'))
    .drop('key', 1)
    .query('station_prev < station_next'))

    station_prev arrival_time_prev  station_next arrival_time_next
1              0             10:00             1             10:02
2              0             10:00             2             10:03
3              0             10:00             3             10:05
6              1             10:02             2             10:03
7              1             10:02             3             10:05
11             2             10:03             3             10:05
```

Comment: This is works really well, thanks a lot for the suggestion!